# Probability of hitting a random number in n steps

Tags: probability

(With random I mean that there is an equal chance between to get any of the numbers in the range given)

I have two random whole number a and b between (and including) 1-100
and a third whole number c that changes every step (random integer 1-6).

Each step (if a≠b) i move b, c steps, in the direction of a.

I wonder how i can calculate the propability for a=b in n steps.

n=0 is obviously 1/100, but how would i go about higher n?

Edit:
Tested it $10^9$ times and it seems like it peaks at $n=9$ with a 4.53% chance, with $n=5$ to $n=14$ all being over 4%.

Comment: If e.g. $b=3$ and $c>3$ do you consider that as "$a=b$" or not?

Comment: I don't, so if a=0 and b=3 and c<3, b would go negative in this step.